# Trouble setting up RSS

Tags: channel

Likely a new n00b question:

I'm having trouble getting my RSS setup and am hoping it's just something simple you can help me out with.

My RSS feed is coming out like this:

[image]

For some reason it's picking up the title correctly, but not the right field. Here's the HTML that I'm using

```
<channel>

<title><![CDATA[matt-steele.com Blog]]></title>
<link>{site_url}</link>
<description>{channel_description}</description>
<dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
<dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
<dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
<dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
<admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />

{exp:channel:entries channel="{blog}" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data|pagination" status="open"}
<item>
  <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
  <link>{title_permalink='blog'}</link>
  <guid>{title_permalink='blog'}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
  <description><![CDATA[{blog_body}]]></description>
  <dc:subject>{exp:xml_encode}{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/categories}{/exp:xml_encode}</dc:subject>
  <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
</item>
{/exp:channel:entries}

</channel>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

The feed is at http://matt-steele.com/feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `channel="{blog}"` to `channel="blog"` without the curly brackets.

Also, you can remove the `status="open"` parameter from your channel:entries tag. This is a default with the tag and doesn't need to be declared.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [sample RSS feed](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/_downloads/sample_rss.txt) provided by EllisLab, and you'll see that you're missing the outer RSS module tags as well as the required document declarations before your `<channel>` XML element.

```
{exp:rss:feed channel="blog"}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
```

Then at the end:

```
</rss>
{/exp:rss:feed}
```

Also, you have `channel="{blog}"` in your Channel Entries tag parameters, when it should just be `channel="blog"` (you're specifying the blog name, not parsing a variable).